# Form dictionary as a parameter in PUT API request - AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, afnetworking-2

Hi I have to update my records to the server using REST API. 
I'm using AFNetworking Library and forming the PUT request parameter format as below

```
{
"type":"goal",
    "field_weight_goal": {
        "und": [
          {
            "value": "60"
          }
        ]
      },
      "field_weight_actual": {
        "und": [
          {
            "value": "90"
          }
        ]
      },
      "field_weight_date": {
        "und": [
          {
            "value": "05-10-2017",
            "format": null,
            "safe_value": "05-10-2017"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

Below is my code.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"type": @"goal",
                             @"field_weight_goal" : @{@"und": @[ @{@"value": self.goalWeightTextField.text } ] },
                             @"field_weight_actual" : @{@"und": @[ @{@"value": self.currentWeightTextField.text } ] },
                             @"field_weight_date" : @{@"und": @[ @{@"value": currentDate, @"format" : [NSNull null] , @"safe_value" : currentDate } ] }
                                 };
```

The value is not updating in the server and I'm getting  error ... Request failed: unacceptable (406). Please help me to correct my dictionary format.
while debugging in xcode my parameter format as below

```
 {
    "field_weight_actual" =     {
        und =         (
                        {
                value = "100.0";
            }
        );
    };
    "field_weight_date" =     {
        und =         (
                        {
                format = "<null>";
                "safe_value" = "04-18-2017";
                value = "04-18-2017";
            }
        );
    };
    "field_weight_goal" =     {
        und =         (
                        {
                value = "90.0";
            }
        );
    };
    type = goal;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you serialize the data to json, and make sure you set content type to json

Comment: It shows error while removing the @ from dictionary @[{@"value"

Comment: using this to code to add content type `manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];`

Comment: Actually I confused. I think your dictionary is not formed well. There is no mac system in front of me. So I am unable test. Please read about dictionary. Print it in console.

Comment: @PhaniRaghu  please see the debugging format which I shared

Comment: I don't see an issue with the creation of your params (`[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` returns the same content as the one you want).

Comment: I am using this to serialize the request and response . Is this correct? `AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[self.keychain stringForKey:@"my_token"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRF-Token"];`